# Why does my .NET Maui control render incorrectly when my project is reloaded but when I'm working with it it renders correctly?

Tags: xaml, maui

Below is the XAML for my control. It is a simple label and image separated by a bar.

```
<Frame BorderColor="Black" BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource PrimaryColor}" Padding="5" CornerRadius="10">

  <VerticalStackLayout>
    <Label Text="00:00" FontSize="32" TextColor="{DynamicResource SecondaryColor}" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    <BoxView Color="Black" HeightRequest="2" />
    <Image Source="icon01d.png" HeightRequest="100" />
  </VerticalStackLayout>
</Frame>
```

While I'm working with the control:
[image: While I'm working with the control]

Reloading my project results in:
[image: Reloading my project results in]

What is the cause of this?

Comment: Testing on Windows, Android (including emulator), or iOS?

Comment: I'm testing on windows using the android emulator

Answer (score 0):

I test your code on my side, and this line:

```
<Label Text="00:00" FontSize="32" TextColor="{DynamicResource SecondaryColor}" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
```

casued an error, so I set the text on the code behind with `"mylabel.Text="00:00"` and the error were disappeared.Also it rendered normally.